# Undeclared struct causes no warnings

Tags: c++, c

The following code compiles fine without any warnings on gcc.

Note that there's no forward declaration for the struct. Is this valid C and/or C++ code?

```
struct Foobar* f;
struct Foobar* fun() { return 0; }

int main() { f = 0; fun(); return 0; }
```

Comment: The structure is *declared*, but not *defined*. Those two terms are often used interchangeably, but they mean different things.

Comment: This is what makes it possible for structures to contain pointers to their own type as members (like linked lists) -- a type does not need to be completely declared in order for a pointer to that type to be valid.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: are you saying that as a "side-effect" it's also a "forward" declaration? Is that part in the grammar a declaration?

Comment: @DevSolar: So far I thought it's possible because the start of the struct definition already declares an incomplete type. Apparently it's not how it works.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath From [this C reference on forward declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct#Forward_declaration): "Note that a new struct name may also be introduced just by using a struct tag within another declaration". So yes it's part of the language. I don't have the specification in front of me, but http://en.cppreference.com/ is usually reliable.

Comment: I do not see a `struct` declaration, but only a pointer to a `struct` declaration. A struct declaration would be `struct Foobar;`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Whether it's the `struct foo` at the beginning of the struct definition, or the `struct foo` at the beginning of the pointer declaration *inside* the struct definition that's doing the forward declaration... gee, there I am thinking I know something, and then you go ahead and dribble doubt all over it. :-D

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This called an opaque structure and is not an error. Since all struct pointers are equally large in C, there is no need to know what fields the struct has as long as you just manipulate pointers to it.

Try defining a variable struct Foobar (no pointer) and you will get an incomplete type error.

This enables you to have types with private fields e.g. the FILE type from stdio.h.

Comment: Not necessarily. *Define* a variable of type `struct Foobar` and you will get an error. Merely declaring a variable without defining it (`extern struct Foobar hello;`) won't give any error.

Answer (score 11):

Valid in C.

```
struct Foobar* f;
```

is the same as:

```
struct Foobar;
struct Foobar* f;
```

In C it declares an *incomplete type* `struct Foobar` and it declares a pointer object to an incomplete type.

The type can be completed in another translation unit. (In C there are 3 kinds of type: object, function and incomplete).

You cannot create objects of an incomplete type or get the size of the type:

```
struct Foobar x; // not valid
sizeof (struct Foobar); // not valid
```

but you can create pointers to incomplete types (`struct Foobar* g;`) or `typedef` (`typedef struct Foobar Foobar;`).

Comment: Would it be legal to have `extern struct Foobar x;` and take its address?

Comment: @supercat: I *imagine* you would get a linker error unless there really is a `struct Foobar x` lying around somewhere.

Comment: @Kevin: Naturally, *someone* would have to have a declaration for it, but the question is whether `extern` should be listed as another allowable scenario from the standpoint of the code which uses the structure for no purpose except to take its address.

Comment: @supercat no, you cannot take the address of an object if there is no definition for the object; this is the same even if the type has been completed.

Comment: @supercat now, you cannot assume there is a definition for the object if the type has been completed because you cannot define an object of an incomplete type.

Comment: @ouah: To clarify, I'm talking about something like a project where `p1.c` contains `struct foo {int x;} dat = {5}; int test(struct foo *param) { return param->x; }` and p2.c to contains `int test(struct foo *param); extern struct foo dat; int main(void) { return test(&dat);}`.  The compiler allows `extern` variables of incomplete array types; is there any reason structure types would need to be different in that regard?

Comment: @supercat assuming in `p2.c` your extern declaration was meant to be before  `test` declaration, there is nothing special in the program your type is completed (in p1.c) and you have a definition for the object so you are allowed to take its address.

Comment: @ouah: Why should the order of the `test` and `extern struct foo dat` declarations in p2.c matter, given that the latter serves only to define a symbol `dat` which is only used in `main`?  My point about complete vs incomplete types is that the compiler processing p2.c never gets to find out what's in `struct foo` before it has to generate code, so as far as the compiler's concerned, that's an incomplete type.  Further, on most platforms it would be possible to replace `p1.c` with an assembly-language file which defines `dat` as being an allocation of some size, but never says what it holds.

Comment: @supercat regarding why the order matters in p2.c: in the function declaration the type is still unknown so there is a declaration for the incomplete structure type at block scope. Then there is a new declaration for the type with the extern, this time at file scope. The two structure type declarations are at different scopes so the two types are considered different. For your second point you are right, the symbol is undefined after the compilation is done, but resolving this for the linker is something not way different than if the extern object declaration was for a basic type like int.